# How to make "stay logged in" work in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: firefox, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am working in a website like https://jira.atlassian.com/ using firefox, after clicking the "log in" on the top right corner, i am taken to the next login page, where on the right of "log in" button, there is this "stay logged in" checkbox, already checked.

I tested it manually. It seems that after i log in successfully, if i do not exit the page by log out,  but simply close the page, the next time i enter https://jira.atlassian.com/, i am already logged in. Ok, make sense.

However, if testing such using selenium webdriver, log in, close page, open page again, the above does not happen.

My question is what is the mechanism for this "stay logged in", is it the same as "remember me"? and how do i make it happen when using selenium webdriver?

Up till now my understanding is:

1. this happens because of cookie
2. cookie is stored in firefox profile
3. selenium start with a default profile that does not include cookie, and can not store cookie during the test

Is there a relatively standard solution for this problem, in java preferably?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, each instance of loading a FF with Selenium opens a stripped browser with no history/cookies/extensions etc. It's as if you have just download FF for the first time and its a fresh copy. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Maybe if you keep the session open by not closing the browser down but log out manually and not closing down the browser. Or open a new tab and opening the same address.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to store the cookies and apply them to your new firefox instance
get the cookies using:

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

and than apply them to your new webdriver instance:

```
for(Cookie cook : cookies) {
    driver.manage().addCookie(cook);
}
```